# can a Robot with ROS_comm draw map using SLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-comm, gmapping, desktop-full

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am new to ROS, i have used to for small projects but i still did not understand it very well.
I have a Robot with raspberry pi on it( raspbian jessie ). i have installed ROS Kinetic  and the ros_comm package.
i followed this page
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi
and i will install the gmapping package. my question is, is that enough to run gmapping ? or do i have to install the
ROS Desktop ?
because from what i understood the ros_comm have no GUI tools. but i have seen people run SLAM on their computers and the rviz instead of running on the robot.

Sorry if i am missing major concept in ROS but i am learning, thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279902/can-a-robot-with-ros_comm-draw-map-using-slam-?/) by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2018-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Map making composes of two main modules .

1. Actual mapiing
2. Localization

Mapping is straight forward if you have a Kinect like sensor (RGB-D) , publish the topics and feed it to gmapping module .
The tricky part is that with the Odometry , odometry can be achieved vai a couple of ways

- Encoders + IMU fusion (EKF based)
- Visual Odometry (rtabmap , ORB-SLAM2...)

If you are lucky enough to have a 360degree lidar , you can use hector mapping (This is a slam algorithm which works without encoder feedback )

---

Originally posted by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) with karma: 142 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-16**:
thanks a lot for the help. yeah i actually happen to have put my hand on RPLIDAR A1.

i will try to look and understand how i can integrate everything together